# Will Face ID work in the dark?

Tags: iphone, ios, face-id

With the announcement of Face ID, I wonder, will work in the dark? For example, a dark room? Does the screen allow enough light for it to work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Face ID works in the dark thanks to the flood illuminator. This means Face ID is not dependent on external light sources or purely the light emitted from the display.

> **Flood Illuminator**
>
> Invisible infrared light helps identify your face even when it’s dark.
>
> [image]

https://www.apple.com/iphone-x/#face-id

Answer (score -2):

Depends if it is really dark Face ID is likely not to work even Face ID needs lots of light to work even with a flashlight you still need extremely high light so the likely answer is a simple NO

Comment: Please see the accepted answer for why the answer is wrong (or just go into a dark room with your iPhone and use FaceID to unlock it).